# Nested queries with multiple objects

Tags: apex, soql, relationships

ust i am wondering why like this , and i know relationships are crazy many times in SFDC
I have a query as below and getting results :

```
select id,name,(select id,name from Batches__r)from Faces__c where Account__r.name='A Place'
```

and i am not getting the value for this  query

```
select id,name,(select id,name from faces__r),(select id,name from Batches__r) from Account where name='A Place'
```

Relationships goes like this : Faces have master detail relationship with Account , Batches have lookup relationship with Account  and Batches have master detail with Faces again

So i wanted to know exact reason why this is happening.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Thanks & Regards
sfdev

Answer (score 0):

At last i just tried different way as in the second query , it executes in Apex Explorer but not in Workbench and developer console correctly

and I just modified my query to retrieve

1. select id,name from Faces__c where Account__r.name=my accountname
2. for(Account a:accounts){
                   List bat=[select id,name,faces__c from batches__c where Faces__c!=null AND Faces__r.Account__r.name=:my accountName];
                        for(Batches__c b: bat){//my adding
                           }

Answer (score -1):

I know it's obvious, but... You know your name filter is different on each query right?

```
Account__r.name='A Place'
```

vs:

```
name='A Place to Store - 16243 '
```

Also, watch out for those trailing spaces on the second query.

Comment: please i am sorry but i am using same name in query and i have updated my question too.i am asking about query is not returning value , it doesn't mean about my data.